# Windows 10 - Adobe Acrobat Pro takes long time to open files

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

please excuse me if this is the wrong site to post this question, that being said...

When I open files with Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017 while **connected** to the internet, it takes ±28s per file per instance, meaning, it takes this long whether it is the first time I open the file or 10th time.  The moment I disconnect from the internet, the files open ±1s.

I blocked internet access to "Acrobat.exe" in Windows firewall without success, therefore it is obvious it must be other application components.

System Specs:
Lenovo X1-Yoga (3rd-Gen)
CPU: i7-8650U
RAM: 16GB
Screen: WQHD Touch
Only these items are upgraded, everything else, is as shipped.

I can provide more system information upon request.

Please help!

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix it? I just googled your question and found the solution, or at least what worked for others. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2015415

Comment: I've only tried firewall settings and airplane mode (which is not practical.)  I did search Google (of course) but the issues I read about, don't relate to the internet connecting.  Can you please point me to these solutions?

Comment: it's about 3 scrolls down, the response from Milan: "Not sure why this is happening. But the fix is to disable the sandbox protection under enhanced security. Edit> Preferences > Security (enhanced) and deselect "Enable protected mode at start up" and click OK. (very important to click ok)"